# Is a self-closing div tag valid in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure what is the difference but doing this works:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

but not this.

```
<div class="clearfix"/>
```

Not sure if there are rules about complete HTML markup and shortcut HTML tag in bootstrap.  In Bootstrap do I need to have my HTML completely typed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag like `<this />` is considered to be *self closing*. Or, according to the specification, a [void element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element).

According to the spec, the *only* elements that are void elements are the following:

> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

For those tags, the end `/` is optional, BTW. So `<br>` is the same as `<br />`.

All other tags **must** have an end tag. Hence why `<div />` is not valid.

Comment: Thanks! Been using JSF components for some time. Never looked at the generated HTML markup.  Good to know bootstrap looks at this.  Is there a link at the documentation where this is stated?

Comment: This is nothing to do with Bootstrap. This is just normal HTML syntax rules. I linked to [the relevant part of the official HTML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> div is a normal element, not a void element

If you working on any IDE, your intellisense will automatically autocomplete.

It also depends upon html versions like HTML 4, XHTML, HTML5.